# Laravel Passport tokensExpireIn seems not working

Tags: laravel, access-token, laravel-passport

i'm using Larave 5.4 passport to create SPA application. However, i was able to make authentication work. but access token are always short-lived tokens with 600s expiration time.

i could not increase expiration time with:

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));

Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
```

it have no effect at all.

any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. However, I do not want to edit vendor. Any other solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personal access tokens are **always long-lived**. Their lifetime is not modified when using the `tokensExpireIn` or `refreshTokensExpireIn` methods - as explained in Laravel's official documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#personal-access-tokens).

The option of editing `PassportServiceProvider.php` in the vendor directory is a bad idea. Every time, you make an update `(e.g composer update/install)` or by another developer in production, code will be reverted to status quo, and it would start failing.

A better approach is to use **Password Grant Tokens**. The **OAuth2** password grant allows your other first-party clients, such as a mobile application, to obtain an access token using an e-mail address / username and password. This allows you to issue access tokens securely to your first-party clients without requiring your users to go through the entire OAuth2 authorization code redirect flow. Be sure that you have duly installed `passport` (See Guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#installation), then run this command

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

Having done this, you can request an access token by issuing a `POST` request to `/oauth/token`. Remember, this route is already registered by the `Passport::routes` method so there is no need to define it manually. If the request is successful, you will receive an `access_token` and  `refresh_token` in the JSON response from the server. See payload sample below:

```
{
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "client_id":"your-client-id",
    "client_secret":"your-client-secret",
    "username":"twady77@gmail.com",
    "password":"123456",
    "scope":""
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":1296000,
"access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjVkMWJjN2NhOTU0ZWU2YTZmOGNkMGEyOTFjOTI5YzU4Zjk3ODk3M2YxZDJmNjQ2NjkyZjhjODQyZjYxNTBjZGRiYzMwY2RjMzRmZjJhYmU1In0.eyJhdWQiOiI4IiwianRpIjoiNWQxYmM3Y2E5NTRlZTZhNmY4Y2QwYTI5MWM5MjljNThmOTc4OTczZjFkMmY2NDY2OTJmOGM4NDJmNjE1MGNkZGJjMzBjZGMzNGZmMmFiZTUiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDkyOTI5MjcsIm5iZiI6MTU0OTI5MjkyNywiZXhwIjoxNTUwNTg4OTI3LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.cSvu30xAT-boA5zmVuxTr0TfH_5MYuVWYi6NVQRbryZSswt8EAFTi5QXHH1f0O63DWnLA6VFBS2AfDe4-ryJZACDnt4gtPJOeuu1rNMZ53MU1vjxnyC8FsYz8v9vmYJsZPKqfTJpuJFYRFh7kkV7uWAmrEkuF3POnDn-GjW50f4i26lIZW5ta5j4nZQrIJCQUEzwXaQtn9H-qef3bTWAaplWaV-k7Blic-0TXXVfWa_CdoKCAzHROVBRWY1Idhe1LJkvGKldUGzUfliiB1x7EVVInq94VYEP5d9__90Z2UMUn5dCEgWkXvcEHYy87_4OSwu4TQk_f3hD82OVOEtJGgPyJqK51WqnQCBYwNtxNjqAW2oaMgpritp3G8nccUiyhkE4Pd_kj3cb2OvSNRXdDS9z-RnJb1OXUkja-4Xe_JfIWUjlTnkss18xMg89hcU_3xtBwUXBWHgffzcbNoI1oOwUL6Whekduiy8csf665v0cnzkPXISmvyGhiMseIlBEN9m9uESaJqD_g7WzbsEs7meI0CAF3230UgrI1MdYSAJMW0mMPF9EScH31a_Qpde5O233Ty6-S4NAp323Wneqs_jpGSfw81CvoI1JeY0hZccRC-MBBsQ2Ox7AM36H5L3p-ybricmT3oCcHEqhufq-ygyfqk1RufJwwRblwYPyaJE",
"refresh_token":"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"
}
```

Comment: As of laravel 5.8, personal access token expiration time can also be set using `personalAccessTokensExpireIn` see the [laravel 5.8 token life time](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#token-lifetimes), if we can set expire time then why not to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this library: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine , and you can look laravel session config options

Comment: this is not related to the access token. it's about csrf_token in form i guess. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

tokenExpireIn() instead of refreshTokensExpireIn() use then solve tokenExpireIn problem.

Answer (score -1):

for passport grant token

```
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(10));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
```

This is only adding 10 minutes of expiry time. Don't know how and why, but instead changing internal codes. I Changed

```
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(10000));
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(12000));
```

Now it's adding 7 days of expiry time. Seems like addDays function adding 10000 minutes.

Answer (score -3):

I have the same issue before for my application, I spent two days try to find what is the problem, The best solution that I came up with is to change the expire date directly in the PassportServiceProvider

Go to vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php line 108

```
new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P1Y')
```

for example to set the expire date to one week

```
new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P1W')
```

I know this is a bad solution for fixing the issue, recently I have found the same issue on Laravel Git repo

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/47

Comment: It's working. thank you. it's not an ideal solution but it's work fine.

Comment: It worked. thanks. btw, editing file in \vendor folder is not recommend solution. It would be not able to work in product or dev environment.

Comment: This is an absolutely invalid solution as the changes will be discarded every time you deploy and the package is updated. It introduces an unpredictable cause of error. Please don't let this be the accepted answer as it may lead more people to implement it in their codebase.