# Laravel 5.4 Passport- API cannot set 30 day expire token

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am Using Laravel 5.4 Passport Authentication. I have a problem to set API token expire date for 30 days. I have tried given code in Laravel documentation but it's not working. In the database, it's showing one year default token expiration date.

I have used

```
public function boot(){

    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();

    Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));

}
```

if there is any solution please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**i also got same issue so.. i used like that**

try to change directly in `PassportServiceProvider.php`

go to `PassportServiceProvider.php` path should be like this

```
projectName/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php
```

> and fine this line

```
new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P1Y')
```

for example set expiry  1 month then

```
new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P1M')
```

for example set expiry  1 week then

```
new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P1W')
```

for example set expiry  5 DAYS then

```
new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P5D')
```

for more DateInterval [see](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

github  issue [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986461/laravel-passport-tokensexpirein-seems-not-working)

stackoverflow question [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986461/laravel-passport-tokensexpirein-seems-not-working)

Comment: Thank you, sir, you saved my time. If I do not get the answer, then I have to make new API authentication way. Thanks a lot